# Need Powershell script to list all files name with filesize in a directory and subdirecties

Tags: powershell, csv

The following script produces results only for the specified directory. I need to output all files with their name and size in a directory and any sub-directories:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Files\17-NRELBLD-02-P1.11\SERVICES\DCFORMS\ –Recurse -File |
    Select-Object Name,@{Name="MB";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Length/1kb)}} | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Files\Vij\Result.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *-append* in the export-csv and you can use wildcard in the *get-childitem* like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Files\17-NRELBLD-02-P1.11\SERVICES\DCFORMS\* –Recurse -File | 
Select-Object Name,@{Name="MB";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Length/1kb)}}  | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Files\Vij\Result.csv -Append
```

Comment: Hi Ranadip,Thanks for your reply, now i getting this error 

• : The term '•' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ •    Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Files\17-NRELBLD-02-P1.11\SERVICES\DCFORMS\* –Recurse - ...
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (•:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @VijayanRavichandran: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable.